# Typeahead search suggestions undefined - Remote Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am trying to make the typeahead remote source to a web method which will be repsond with results in JSON format.

Ajax is getting success and it;s returing the results properly . The console in the below code will print like below

> [{"Id":"1","Value":"Midhun"},{"Id":"2","Value":"Midhun2"}]

But the typeahead suggestions are all undefined

> var typeHeadEngine = new Bloodhound({
>           name: 'Name',
>           remote: { url: 'page.aspx/method',
>
> ```
>         ajax: {
>             type: "POST",
>             data: JSON.stringify({ "query": '%QUERY' }),
>             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>             dataType: "text",                
>             success: function (data) {
>                 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
>                 console.log(obj.d);
>                 return obj.d;
>             }
>
>         }
>
>     },
>     datumTokenizer: function (d) {
>         return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
>     },
>     queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
> });
>
> typeHeadEngine .initialize();
>
> $('.typeahead').typeahead({
>     hint: true,
>     highlight: true,
> ```
>
> > ```
> >     minLength: 3
> > },   {
> >   name: 'Name',
> >   displayKey: 'Value',
> >   source: typeHeadEngine.ttAdapter()
> > ```
> >
> > });

Web method is returing JSON string which am converting to array in the ajax success function. During googling i found that typeahead requires array and not JSON object ,so I am converting into array.

i went through plently of similar questions to figure it out. But i am unable to do so ,
Can anyone please help to figure out what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `success` field of the ajax options to transform your JSON,
instead you have to use the `filter` field provided by Bloodhound:

```
var typeHeadEngine = new Bloodhound({
name: 'Name',
remote: {
    url: 'page.aspx/method',
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "query": '%QUERY'
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text"
    },
    filter: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj.d);
        return obj.d;
    }
},
datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
},
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) , a minor change is required to done in the filter section as filter should return ojects .We need to change the  return obj.d; to return eval(obj.d) in the code .

Comment: After we do `JSON.parse(data)`, `obj` and `obj.d` are already parsed into JS objects, hence the code above should work (and it did in my tests). Also, calling `eval()` is a little suspect IMHO.
If you had to use eval, maybe your JSON is formatted incorrectly?

Comment: I have the same JSON format as in the example mentoined in the above question. May be onething i am not returning the JSON result in JSON format i am sending across it as text .

Comment: sorry i mean the result is transfered as plain text not as JSON Response.